# How can I handle whitespace when using `deparse(substitute))` (or an alternative)?

Tags: r

I'm writing some code that translates mathematical function definitions to valid R code. Therefore I use `deparse(substitute))` to access those function definitions in order I can alter them to valid R code.

---

For example I have the function `LN(x)^y` that should become `log(x)^y`. I can do this using the first version of my `to_r` function:

```
to_r <- function(x) {
  parse(text = gsub("LN", "log", deparse(substitute(x))))
}
to_r(LN(x)^y)
```

This returns `expression(log(x)^y)` which is what I expect.

---

I also get function definitions looking like `LN("x a")^y`. To handle those I can expand my function:

```
to_r_2 <- function(x) {
  parse(text = gsub(" ", "_", gsub("\"", "", gsub("LN", "log", deparse(substitute(x))))))
}
to_r_2(LN("x a")^y)
```

This returns `expression(log(x_a)^y)` which is fine.

---

However, when my input becomes something like `LN("x a")*2^y` this fails:

```
parse(text = gsub(" ", "_", gsub("\"", "", gsub("LN", "log", deparse(substitute(LN("x a")*2^y))))))
```

> Error in parse(text = gsub(" ", "_", gsub("\"", "", gsub("LN", "log", 
>   :    :1:9: unexpected input 1: log(x_a)_
>               ^

The reason is that `deparse(substitute(LN("x a")*2^y))` introduces whitespaces around `*` and afterwards I `gsub` those whitespaces with underscores which is a problem for `parse`.

---

Is there a way to solve this?
Maybe an alternative to `deparse(substitute))`?

*(To state the obvious: Replacing `gsub(" ", "_", x)` with `gsub(" ", "", x)` is not really an option because variable names get unreadable. For example `Reason one of Something` would become `ReasononeofSomething` which is far less readable than the attempted `Reason_one_of_Something`.)*

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Can you clearly identify what the raw input is (string? quoted expression? promise?) and what the desired output for that input is. Maybe separate your code into a function so we can clearly see which parts we can change. I'm not sure exactly what your rules are for parsing invalid statements.

Comment: @MrFlick: The idea is to put it inside a function in order to have calls like: `to_r(LN(x)^y)`, see my edit.

Comment: But you'd never be able to call `to_r_2(LN(x a)^y)`. If you are passing an expression, it needs to use valid R syntax. How do you know whey the are actually trying to pass a string to your function? Do you want to replace every string with a symbol?

Comment: @MrFlick: You're right. `to_r_2(LN(x a)^y` will never work. I removed that case. Is there still a way to handle the `to_r_2(LN("x a")*2^y` case?

Comment: I thought the gsub would be a perfect use case for `rapply` but it doesn't treat calls as lists unfortunately... It would have been nice though... `rapply(x,function(x) as.symbol(gsub(" ","_",x)), "character", how = "replace")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a helper function to replace any character values in an expression with symbols (with spaces replaced with underscores)

```
chr_to_sym <- function(x) {
  if (is(x, "call")) {
    as.call(do.call("c",lapply(as.list(x), chr_to_sym), quote=T))
  } else if (is(x, "character")) {
    as.symbol(gsub(" ","_", x))
  } else {
    x
  }
}
```

We can then use that in your translation function

```
to_r <- function(x) {
  expr <- substitute(x)
  expr <- do.call("substitute", list(expr, list(LN=quote(log))))
  as.expression(chr_to_sym(expr))
}
```

note that this version works with the expressions directly. It doesn't do any deparsing/string manipulation. This is generally safer. This works for the examples you provide

```
to_r(LN(x)^y)
# expression(log(x)^y)
to_r(LN("x a")^y)
# expression(log(x_a)^y)
to_r(LN("x a")*2^y)
# expression(log(x_a) * 2^y)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input is an R call object then it must, of course, conform to R syntax.  In that case we can process it using a recursive function that walks through the input and replaces names containing a space or spaces with the same name but with underscore instead of space(s).  Also, at the end replaces LN with log.  A call object is returned.

```
rmSpace <- function(e) {
    if (length(e) == 1) e <- as.name(gsub(" ", "_", as.character(e)))
      else for (i in 1:length(e)) e[[i]] <- Recall(e[[i]])
    do.call("substitute", list(e, list(LN = as.name("log"))))
}
rmSpace(quote(LN("x a")*2^y))
## log(x_a) * `2`^y

# to input an expression add [[1]] after it to make it a call object
rmSpace(expression(LN("x a")*2^y)[[1]])
## log(x_a) * `2`^y
```

Apply as.expression to the result if you want an expression instead of call object.

If the input is a character string then we can simply replace `LN` with `log` and for any space of spaces having digit or letter on both sides we can replace the space(s) with an underscore.  We return a string or an call object depending on the second argument.

```
rmSpace2 <- function(s, retclass = c("character", "call")) {
  s1 <- gsub("\\bLN\\b", "log", s)
  s2 <- gsub("([[:alnum:]]) +([[:alnum:]])", "\\1_\\2", s1, perl = TRUE)
  retclass <- match.arg(retclass)
  if (retclass == "character") s2 else parse(text = s2)[[1]]
}
rmSpace2("LN(x a)*2^y")
## [1] "log(x_a)*2^y"

rmSpace2("LN(x a)*2^y", "call")
## log(x_a) * 2^y
```

If you want an expression instead of a call object use `as.expression`:

```
as.expression(rmSpace2("LN(x a)*2^y", "call"))
## expression(log(x_a) * 2^y)
```